# Prove that the set $U = \{(123), (124), ... , (12n)\}$ can be used to generate $A_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, permutations

A hint is provided with the proof prompt:
$(abc) = (1ca)(1ab)$, $(1ab) = (1b2)(12a)(12b)$, and $(1b2) = (12b)^2$.

My idea:
$(1ab) = (12b)(12b)(12a)(12b)$.
To solve for the other half of $(abc)$, I'm guessing $(1a2) = (12a)(12a)$. Thus, $(1ca) = (1a2)(12c)(12a)$
Therefore, $(abc) = (1a2)(12c)(12a)(1b2)(12a)(12b)$

Thus, $A_n$ can be written using only variations of $(12n)$.
 Is this a sufficient proof? Are there other cases to be proven? Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: So far you've only talked about $3$-cycles; $A_n$ contains many more types of elements than that.

Comment: I assumed the proof was talking about $A_n$ in its entirety only. Should I also prove for 2-cycles and then make a note of the ability to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

The hint tells you that each 3-cycle can be generated by elements of $U$.

So what is missing is to show that each element in $A_n$ can be written as a product of 3-cycles of $S_n$.

Each 3-cycle $(a\; b\; c)$ lies in $A_n$, as it can be written as $(a\; b) \circ (b \; c)$.

Furthermore each permutation in $A_n$ is a product of 3-cycles, because pairs of transpositions can be written as product of 3-cycles.

Just look at the possible cases when taking any pair of transposition:

- $(a \; b) \circ (a \; b) = id = (a \; b \; c) \circ (c \; b \; a)$ (if the transpositions are equal)
- $(a \; b) \circ (a \; c) = (a \; c \; b)$ (if the transpositions differ in exactly one element)
- $(a \; b) \circ (c \; d) = (a \; c \; b) \circ (a \; c \; d)$ (if the transpositions differ in two elements)